# How to personalize Select Query with C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a function that allows to get the SELECT query dynamically. So I thought about using string.join and string.format but I couldn't do it. Below is my code:

```
private void ExecuteQuery()
{
    string databaseName = "Cars";
    string tableName= "Berline";
    List<string> colNames = new List<string>{"NAME","TYPE","REV"};
    List<string> colValues = new List<string>{"Nitro","N1-55","1.00"};
    Console.WriteLine( GetSelectQuery( databaseName , tableName, colNames , colValues );
}
private string GetSelectQuery( string databaseName, string tableName, List<string> colNames, List<string> colValues)
{
     var selectColValuesQuery = string.Format( "{0} = {1}", colNames.Select(n => string.Format("`{0}`", n)), colValues.Select(n => string.Format("'{0}'", n)));
     return string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}.{1} WHERE {2};", databaseName, tableName, selectColValuesQuery);
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
SELECT * FROM `Cars`.`Berline` WHERE `NAME`='Nitro' AND `TYPE`='N1-55' AND `REV`='1.00';
```

Comment: This is just asking for trouble in the form of escaping troubles (and possible SQL injection). Any reason you disdain the use of established libraries and frameworks like Dapper and EF, beyond "not invented here"? Even without those you want to give your own little ORM the ability to use parameters rather than interpolated strings, at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Parameter` class to store your key/value pair.

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `string.join` to with lambda to concat values.

```
private static void ExecuteQuery()
{
    string databaseName = "Cars";
    string tableName = "Berline";
    List<Parameter> para=new List<Parameter>()
    {
        new Parameter()
        {
            Key = "NAME",
            Value = "Nitro"
        },
        new Parameter()
        {
            Key = "TYPE",
            Value = "N1-55"
        },
        new Parameter()
        {
            Key = "REV",
            Value = "1.00"
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(GetSelectQuery(databaseName, tableName, para));
}

private static string GetSelectQuery(string databaseName, string tableName, List<Parameter> para)
{
   
    var selectColValuesQuery = string.Join(" AND ", para.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}").ToArray());
    return $"SELECT * FROM {databaseName}.{tableName} WHERE {selectColValuesQuery};";
}
```

**Note:**

I would suggest use [Parameterize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of concat SQL string to avoid [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a parameterized command to avoid injection you could use something like:

```cs
private void ExecuteQuery(SqlConnection mySqlConnection, SqlTransaction mySqlTransaction)
        {
            string databaseName = "Cars";
            string tableName = "Berline";
            List<string> colNames = new List<string> { "NAME", "TYPE", "REV" };
            List<string> colValues = new List<string> { "Nitro", "N1-55", "1.00" };



            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GetSelectQuery(databaseName, tableName, colNames), mySqlConnection, mySqlTransaction))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < colNames.Count; i++)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val"+i, colValues[i]);

                //Execute your query and read values
            }
               
        }


        private string GetSelectQuery(string databaseName, string tableName, List<string> colNames)
        {
            string[] whereConditions = new string[colNames.Count];
            for(int i=0; i< colNames.Count; i++)
                whereConditions[i] = colNames[i] + "=@val" + i;

            string selectColValuesQuery = string.Join(" AND ", whereConditions);
             return string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}.{1}] WHERE {2};", databaseName, tableName, selectColValuesQuery);
        }
```

Unfortunately, I think there is no way to get the final command string printed (at least, I couldn't). It would be nice if someone knows how when using parameterized commands.